# Why listbox is always editable at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, save, edit

In my View class, I've a listbox control. It includes stackpanel of textboxes and comboboxes. But what I don't understand is that when I run the application, data of the listbox is erased? What should I do if I want to avoid this?

I want listbox contents to be editable when I click on edit button of my window.
Please also suggest me ways of making listbox contents editable.

My listbox is

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,131,0,59" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" SelectionMode="Single"/>

<!-- Default DataTemplate -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StartTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StopTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ProjectNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130"/>  
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Editable DataTemplate -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableDataTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <!--<ComboBox x:Name="ClientComboBox" SelectionChanged="ClientComboBoxChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=clientList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name" SelectedItem="{Binding ClientNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="145"/>-->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StartTimeBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding StopTimeBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ProjectComboBox" SelectionChanged="ProjectComboBoxChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=projectList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name"  SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="71" Background="Yellow" BorderThickness="0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>


        <!-- DataTemplate Selector -->

        <l:DayViewListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
          DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
          EditableDataTemplate="{StaticResource EditableDataTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: Start with getting the data to display.  Suspect a problem with your binding.  The may help you find the problem PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High".   For non-edit can use IsReadonly = true or a TextBlock.

Comment: Thanks, Blam. Using TextBlock instead TextBox solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For non-edit can use IsReadonly = true or a TextBlock.